# How do I see a detailed order (execution) for a Prolog query?

Tags: prolog, visualization, visualizer

Let's say I have this Prolog program:

```
loves(vincent, mia).
loves(marcellus, mia).
jealous(A, B) :- loves(A, C), loves(B, C).
```

With query `jealous(A,B).` I'm very new to Prolog and I'd like to know how is it possible to see the exact order the program will be running and taking its ways for this query? I have tried using `trace, jealous(A,B).` command but it has only given me that:

Isn't there any more detailed solution for that? :/

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen the [Prolog Visualizer](http://www.cdglabs.org/prolog/#/)?

When you get to the page be sure to click on the icons in the upper right to learn more.

[image]

Enjoy.

---

Screenshot after step 10 of 49.

[image]

Screenshot for example given after all steps.

[image]

---

The Prolog Visualizer uses a slightly nonstandard way to enter a query by ending the query with a question mark (?), e.g.

```
jealous(A,B)?
```

If you **do not** post a query in the input area on the left you will receive an error, e.g.

[image]

The input for the Prolog Visualizer for your example is

```
loves(vincent, mia).
loves(marcellus, mia).
jealous(A, B) :- loves(A, C), loves(B, C).
jealous(A,B)?
```

When the Prolog Visualizer completes your example, notice the four results in green on the right

[image]

---

If you are using [SWI-Prolog](https://www.swi-prolog.org/) and after you understand [syntactic unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)#Examples_of_syntactic_unification_of_first-order_terms), [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) and write more advanced code you will find this of use:

[Overview of the SWI Prolog Graphical Debugger](https://blog.inductorsoftware.com/blog/SWIPrologGraphicalDebugger)

---

For other useful Prolog references see: [Useful Prolog references](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/useful-prolog-references/1089)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed thank you so much! :)

Comment: @eyesima You are welcome. The real thanks should go to the [authors](https://github.com/cdglabs/prolog-viz#credit) of the code and [Falco](https://github.com/fnogatz?tab=repositories) who had a link to it that lead me to the code.

Answer (score 1):

If the Prolog system has callable_property/2 and sys_rule/3, then one can code
a smart "unify" port as follows, showing most general unifiers (mgu's`):

```
:- op(1200, fx, ?-).

% solve(+Goal, +Assoc, +Integer, -Assoc)
solve(true, L, _, L) :- !.
solve((A, B), L, P, R) :- !, solve(A, L, P, H), solve(B, H, P, R).
solve(H, L, P, R) :- functor(H, F, A), sys_rule(F/A, J, B),
   callable_property(J, sys_variable_names(N)),
   number_codes(P, U), atom_codes(V, [0'_|U]), shift(N, V, W),
   append(L, W, M), H = J, reverse(M, Z), triage(M, Z, I, K),
   offset(P), write_term(I, [variable_names(Z)]), nl,
   O is P+1, solve(B, K, O, R).

% triage(+Assoc, +Assoc, -Assoc, -Assoc)
triage([V=T|L], M, R, [V=T|S]) :- var(T), once((member(W=U, M), U==T)), W==V, !,
   triage(L, M, R, S).
triage([V=T|L], M, [V=T|R], S) :-
   triage(L, M, R, S).
triage([], _, [], []).

% shift(+Assoc, +Atom, -Assoc)
shift([V=T|L], N, [W=T|R]) :-
   atom_concat(V, N, W),
   shift(L, N, R).
shift([], _, []).

% offset(+Integer)
offset(1) :- !.
offset(N) :- write('\t'), M is N-1, offset(M).

% ?- Goal
(?- G) :-
   callable_property(G, sys_variable_names(N)),
   shift(N, '_0', M),
   solve(G, M, 1, _).
```

Its not necessary to modify mgu's retrospectively, since a solution to a
Prolog query is the sequential composition of mgu's. Here is an example run:

```
?- ?- jealous(A,B).
[A_0 = X_1, B_0 = Y_1]
    [H_1 = mia, X_1 = vincent]
    [Y_1 = vincent]
A = vincent,
B = vincent ;
    [Y_1 = marcellus]
A = vincent,
B = marcellus ;
Etc..
```

This is a preview of Jekejeke Prolog 1.5.0 the new
predicate sys_rule/3, its inspired by the new
predicate [rule/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=rule/2) of SWI-Prolog, but keeps the
clause/2 argument of head and body and uses a predicate
indicator.